# rendering <input type ='submit'> using InnerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am currently working on a web forms project and in the code behind I use InnerHtml to loop through a list of items to display it.

something like this.

```
email = v.DomainObjectFields.Where(t => t.FieldName == "Email Address").First().FieldValue;
            name = v.DomainObjectFields.Where(t => t.FieldName == "First Name").First().FieldValue;
            familyName = v.DomainObjectFields.Where(t => t.FieldName == "Last Name").First().FieldValue;
            dateJoined = v.DomainObjectFields.Where(t => t.FieldName == "Date Joined").First().FieldValue;

            Users.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "<a href='UserDetail.aspx?username=" + email + "'>"+email+"</a>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += name;
            Users.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += familyName;
            Users.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += dateJoined;
            Users.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            **Users.InnerHtml += "<input type='button' id='butResetPassword' value='Resend Password'/>";**
            Users.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            Users.InnerHtml += "</tr>";

<div id="Users" runat="server">

</div>
```

The button however is not rendering and I need to add a button to the grid display. Is there a way of adding a button and a handler with the way I am doing it now?

Comment: is this rendering inside a form element ? If not, this might be the issue . Also you don't show the table element. It would also be way more efficient to store the markup in a StringBuilder and set the InnerHtml property just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a repeater or DataList?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     rptUsers.DataSource = users;
     rptUsers.DataBind();
}

protected void rptUsers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {
         User user = (User)e.Item.DataItem;
         Label email = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("email");
         Label name = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("name");
         Label familyname = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("familyname");
         Label datejoined = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("datejoined");

         email.Text = user.EmalAddress;
         name.Text = user.Name;
         familyname.Text = user.FamilyName;
         datejoined.Text = user.DateJoined.ToString();
      }
 }

 protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //submit
 }
```

Basic markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptUsers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptUsers_OnItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label id="email" runat="server" />
      <asp:Label id="name" runat="server" />
      <asp:Label id="familyname" runat="server" />
      <asp:Label id="datejoined" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" Text="Submit" />
```

You can of course use a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx) which is set up in much the same way except it can render a table for you which appears to be what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in following where href is not properly getting created.

```
 Users.InnerHtml += "<a href='UserDetail.aspx?username=" + email + "'>"+email+"</a>";
```

Try to resolve this by replacing this line with

```
Users.InnerHtml += "<a href='UserDetail.aspx?username='" + email + "''>"+email+"</a>";
```